# Create page dynamically in Asp.net - c#

Tags: asp.net

Hi i want to create an asp.net application where i need to provide specific URL for each user in my website dynamically..

Comment: Please re-word your question, as it does not make sense.

Comment: Your edit didnt help, made it worse if anything. Elaborate on your question, don't remove parts of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can intercept the HttpApplication.BeginRequest event and check if the Request url is one of your dynamic URLs, and if it is, redirect to a non-dynamic URL, after setting some Session level or QueryString variables.

Alternatively, you could a custom route:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: Exactly. I think you're looking for URL rewriting. If so, do some Googling and you'll find a dozen articles and samples.